# How does image anchoring work in Reality Composer?

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

Whilst learning about Reality Composer I found that it is possible to anchor an image using Reality Composer, meaning if I have an image in real life and a copy of it in the Reality Composer then using that I can build a whole scene right on top of the image. I was wondering, how does the actual anchoring happen?

I have worked before with SIFT keypoint matching, which could be used in this case as well, however, I cannot find how this works in Reality Composer.

Answer (score 0):

The principle of operation is as simple as that:

Reality Composer's scene element called `AnchorEntity` contained in `.rcproject` file in RealityKit app conforms to [HasAnchoring](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/hasanchoring) protocol. When RealityKit app's Artificial Intelligence sees any image thru rear camera, it compares it with the one containing inside reference image folder. If both images are identical, app creates an image-based anchor `AnchorEntity` (similar to ARImageAnchor in ARKit) that tethers its corresponding 3D model. Invisible anchor appears in the center of a picture.

```swift
AnchorEntity(.image(group: "ARResourceGroup", name: "imageBasedAnchor"))
```

When you're using image-based anchors in RealityKit apps, you're using a RealityKit's analog of [ARImageTrackingConfig](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arimagetrackingconfiguration) that is less processor intensive than ARWorldTrackingConfig.

The difference between `AnchorEntity(.image)` and `ARImageAnchor` is that RealityKit automatically tracks all its anchors, while ARKit uses `renderer(...)` or `session(...)` methods for updating.